# Taking a list of tuples as an argument and returning a dictionary as a result

Tags: python, dictionary

If I have a list of tuples like so.

`friendface = [('zeus','apollo'),('zeus','aphrodite'), ('apollo','aphrodite'), ('athena','hera'), ('hera','aphrodite'), ('aphrodite','apollo'), ('aphrodite','zeus'), ('athena','aphrodite'), ('aphrodite','athena'), ('zeus','athena'), ('zeus','hera')`

I want to write a function called **likes_relation(friendface)** which return a dictionary which shows who each person is linked with, the solution should look something like this..

```
>>> likes_relation(friendface)

{'Aphrodite': ['Apollo', 'Zeus', 'Athena'],
'Hera': ['Aphrodite'],
'Zeus': ['Apollo', 'Aphrodite', 'Athena', 'Hera'],
'Apollo': ['Aphrodite'],
'Athena': ['Hera', 'Aphrodite'] }
```

If someone knows how this can be done I'd appreciate the help as it's really starting to annoy me now.

Thanks!

EDIT : I've currently got a bit of terrible code.

```
def likes_relation(friendface):
    dict_friends = dict(friendface)
    for name in friendface:
        if name not in dict(friendface):        
            #dict(friendface)[name[:] = name[1]
  #What i'm trying to do is go and run through the list
  # again and if one of the sets isn't in the dictionary
  # then add it.... obviously i don't know how...
```

return dict(friendface)

Comment: Oh didn't see that one DSM, it's the same freaking paper.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)
map(lambda entry: result[entry[0]].append(entry[1]), friendface)
```

Comment: You don't need the `map` here.